# Can't access Star Trek Online game servers

Tags: wireless-networking, gaming

I recently upgraded to a fibre broadband from VDSL. Everything was doing well, a lot faster than before i.e. Youtube, Blizzard games, Steam etc.

However I do play a game called Star Trek Online. For some reason I am unable to connect to the game servers. I did try using my older connection and it is working perfectly well. This old connection will be disconnected soon and I won't be able to play this game anymore.

I have Windows 10, I already tried shutting down Windows Defender - the game still doesn't work. I thought I would try port forwarding... may not be the solution but still, the game is not working either.

Comment: If you connect to a VPN are you able to connect?

Comment: Have you asked your new ISP?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have changed the modem and router along with the new connection, This will mean that you have a fresh configuration on the new router.

You most likely need to port forward the ports required for Star Trek online

quick Google search of [star trek online port forwarding](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=star%20trek%20online%20port%20forwarding) should help.

what is the model of your router?